# How to install valgrind on mac os 10.9

Tags: valgrind

Port does not support installing valgrind on the latest mac os. And I could not compile it from source code. I am wondering if someone has installed it on mac os 10.9. Here is the error message I got:

```
./autogen.sh
running: aclocal
running: autoheader
autoheader: error: AC_CONFIG_HEADERS not found in configure.ac
error: while running 'autoheader'
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed it from a patched branch [here](https://github.com/fredericgermain/valgrind/), this is how my installation worked, try following the steps::

```
//Make sure you have autoconf and automake both are installed.
sudo port -v install automake
sudo port -v install autoconf

//get patched valgrind on "homebrew" branch
cd ~/some_directory  
git clone https://github.com/fredericgermain/valgrind/ -b homebrew
cd valgrind

//clone it
git submodule init
git submodule update

//compile valgrind
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install

//confirm installation
calvin % which valgrind
```